# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string specific date format

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT CAST('Tue Aug 28 2018 16:24:58' AS datetime)
```

I am getting error on conversion of nchar to datetime.

Comment: remove the day name.  Also get familiar with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles

Comment: Remove the day:  SELECT CAST('Aug 28 2018 16:24:58' AS datetime)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. That error is because that string is not able to be implicitly converted to a datetime. If you remove the day portion it would work. Can you change the source data?

Comment: I'm surprised you're getting an `nchar` error with that SQL; that literal string is a `varchar`. A `nchar`/`nvarchar` literal string starts with a `N` I.e. `N'This is a literal nvarchar string'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the day name (Tue in your case):

```
SELECT CAST('Aug 28 2018 16:24:58' AS datetime)
```

Return:

```
28.08.2018 16:24:58
```

Answer (score 0):

You code converts fine without the day of the week.

An easy way to get rid of it uses `stuff()`:

```
SELECT CAST(STUFF('Tue Aug 28 2018 16:24:58', 1, 4, '') AS datetime)
```